# Determining Whether or Not (L, +, *) is a K-Linear Space Under These Operations and Justify Your Conclusion.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Question:
"Let $L = K^2$, where $K$ is a field. (Note: By convention, $0 \neq 1$ in any field). Define operations $+$ and $\cdot$ on $L$ by $(x,y) + (u,v) = (x + u, y + v)$ and $c\cdot (x,y) = (cx,y)$ for $c,x,y,u,v$ in $K$. Determine whether or not $(L, +, \cdot)$ is a $K$-linear space under these operations, and justify your conclusion."

What I Have Attempted: I need to either prove that all eight axioms hold, or that at least one does not hold. I believe Axioms 2, 7, & 8 do not hold.

The eight axioms are

1. Associativity under vector addition
2. Commutativity under vector addition
3. Existence of a vector identify element
4. Existence of a vector inverse element for all vectors
5. Associativity under scalar multiplication
6. Existence of a scalar identify element
7. Scalar multiplication is distributive over vector addition
8. Scalar addition is distributive over vector multiplication(pretty sure this is the incorrect terminology, please correct if so)

Axiom 1:True
Let $(w,z)$ be a vector in $L$
Then
$(u,v) + ((x,y) + (w,z)) = (u,v) + (x + w, y + z) = (u + x + w, v + y + z)$
and
$((u,v) + (x,y)) + (w,z) = (u + x, v + y) + (w,z) = (u + x + w, v + y + z)$

Axiom 2:False
$(u,v) + (x,y) = (u + x, v + y) \neq (x + u, y + v)$

Axiom 3:True
Let the vector identity element be equal to $(0,0)$
Then
$(x,y) + (0,0) = (x + 0, y + 0) = (x,y)$

Axiom 4:True
Let $-$ denote a vectors inverse element
Then
$(x,y) + (-x,-y) = (x + -x,y + -y) = (0,0)$

Axiom 5:True
Let $a$ be an element of K
Then
$a\cdot (c\cdot (x,y)) = a\cdot (cx,y) = (acx,y)$ and $(a\cdot c)\cdot (x,y) = (ac)\cdot (x,y) = (acx,y)$

Axiom 6:True
Let the scalar ientity element be equal to $1$
Then
$1\cdot (x,y) = (1x,y) = (x,y)$

Axiom 7:False
$c\cdot ((x,y) + (u,v)) = c\cdot ((x + u, y + v)) = (c(x + u), y + v)$
and
$c\cdot (x,y) + c\cdot (u,v) = (cx,y) + (cu,v) = (cx + cu, y + v) \neq (c(x + u), y + v)$

Axiom 8:False
$(a + c)\cdot (x,y) = ((a+c)x,y)$
and
$a\cdot (x,y) + c\cdot (x,y) = (ax,y) + (cx,y) = (ax + cx,y) \neq ((a+c)x,y)$

Questions:
Do we assume that the operations images follow the axioms? For example, should I be able to assume that $(u + x, v + y) = (x + u, y + v)$ because it is an image from $L$ to $L$ or am I correct in saying the axiom does not hold? Are there any other mistakes you see in the other axioms.

Comment: Wikipedia calls the eighth axiom "distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field addition", for what its worth.

Comment: What's the difference of field addition vs vector addition?

Comment: Field addition is the operation of adding elements of $K$, while vector addition is the operation of adding elements of $L$. So the two are defined on different sets. Does that answer your question?

Comment: We use the definition provided in the problem for the vector addition and the fields own rules of addition for the scalars (in this case $K^n$)? (I think may clear up the questions on your answer too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $(u+x,v+y) = (x+u,y+v)$ does hold. This might be more immediate to you if you think of $K = \mathbb{R}$. For example $(2+3,3+4) = (3+2,4+3)$, since both terms are equal to $(5,7)$; the only thing that differs is the way we chose to wrote the numbers. Similarly, since addition is commutative in a field, $u+x = x+u$ for any $u,x \in K$, and so $(u+x,v+y) = (x+u,y+v)$ just because these ordered pairs are made up of the same field elements, in the same order (though we wrote them differently). The same holds for Axiom $7$: by virtue of $K$ being a field we have that $c(x + u) = cx + cu$ for any $c,x,u \in K$, and similarly for Axiom $8$.

Thus your arguments for the falsehood of Axioms $2,7,8$ are wrong. However, in the case of the $8$-th axiom you made another mistake as well. Can you see it? Again, you might consider a concrete example, e.g. compare $(1+1) \cdot (1,1)$ and $1\cdot (1,1) + 1\cdot (1,1)$.

Comment: So when we take the pre-image from the set "through" the operators of the field we can assume that their images follow the axioms of that field?  
For Axiom 8: Is that not what I've done?

Comment: I don't quite follow your question -- the pre-image of which set, under what function? As for Axiom $8$: there is a mistake in your calculations. You write $(ax,y) + (cx,y) = (ax+cx,y)$, but that is not true in general.

Comment: When we take the preimage of the elements of the set $L$ under the additive and multiplicative operators from the field. The vector space does two things $L\times L \to L$ and $K\times L \to L$? So can we assume that the $L$ that these two binary operators image to follow the axioms?
Using the same reasoning from above, shouldn't the $(ax,y) + (cx,y)$ be a vector and thus work under the vector addition rule $(x,y) + (u,v) = (x + u, y + v)$ where $ax = x$ and $cx = u$?

Comment: I think I may have found my point of misunderstanding. When we have the "image" of the vector addition or scalar multiplication, [$(x + u, y + v)$ or $(cx,y)$ respectively] that part abides by the axioms of the field that the vector space is over? Meaning we know that the second axiom holds because in $K^2$ $x + u = u + x$.

Comment: We have $x+ u = u + x$ for $u,v \in K$ because field addition is commutative, and in the second axiom $(u+x,v+y) = (x+u,y+v)$, because in the ordered paris the corresponding elements are equal (note that we didn't explicitly define "vector equality", but that's not a problem because we know when two ordered pairs are equal - it's precisely when the corresponding elements are equal).

Comment: The addition of vectors follows the rule of vector addition defined above, but in this case "within" the vector are elements of the field, and these, of course, follow the field axioms. Again, for $K = \mathbb{R}$, consider $(2,3) + (3,4) = (2+3,3+4) = (5,7)$. The first of these equalities uses the definition of vector addition, but for the second equality we don't have to "assume" anything about the vector space - we just use our knowledge that $2+3$ and $5$ are just different ways of writing the same thing in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That connection of what constitutes vector vs scalar addition being "outside" and "within" the field was what I was having trouble with.